# How can I pass optional arguments on to another function which has optional arguments

Tags: vba, function, excel, argument-passing

I have a function called myfunction. it has 10 optional arguments. This calls another function called myotherfunction which has the same 10 optional arguments.

So let's say I call myfunction with only argument one.  How do I call myotherfunction using only argument one when I don't know which of the 10 optional arguments have been passed?

I can't say ret_value=myotherfunction(arg1:=argumentone) because there could be between 1 and 10 arguments that I need to pass. If I used 2 arguments then it would have to be ret_value=myotherfunction(arg1:=argumentone, arg2:=argumenttwo) but again at run time I don't know which arguments have been passed to myfunction. Is there a way to parse a function call?

Answer (score 2):

Just pass the arguments along the chain. As a very simplistic example:

```
Sub foo()
    Call bar("test")
End Sub
Sub bar(sOne As String, Optional sTwo)
    Call foobar(sOne, sTwo)
End Sub
Sub foobar(strOne As String, Optional strTwo)
    If IsMissing(strTwo) Then
        MsgBox strOne
    Else
        MsgBox strOne & "- " & strTwo
    End If
End Sub
```

Note: the IsMissing in Foobar is only to indicate that each routine needs to test the optional arguments before doing anything with them. Perhaps a clearer example of just passing them on is:

```
Sub foo()
   ' note only one parameter provided
    Call bar("test")
End Sub
Sub bar(sOne As String, Optional sTwo, Optional sThree, Optional sFour)
     ' still pass all parameters even if we only got one
    Call foobar(sOne, sTwo, sThree, sFour)
End Sub
Sub foobar(strOne As String, Optional strTwo, Optional strThree, Optional strFour)
   ' some code here
End Sub
```

Comment: The trouble is there may be any combination of 10 variables. I can certainly use ismissing to find out which variables have been passed in at run time, but how do I construct the second function call at the design stage to cater for all these combinations?

Comment: I think you're missing my point. Just pass *all the same variables* from the first routine to the second. Don't bother testing them. Note the `Call foobar(sOne, sTwo)` doesn't check, or care, whether sTwo was passed to `bar` or not, it just passes it along. To be honest, 10 optional arguments seems like bad design to me - perhaps you need a ParamArray, or a UDT/Class.

Comment: Well I suppose I was looking for a more elegant solution. But it doesn't look like there is one. The 10 optional arguments are used by the API I am sending requests to. I can't change that. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is inelegant here?

Answer (score 1):

Use `IsMissing`.

```
If IsMissing(arg1) Then
    'do something
End If
```

It works only for `Variant` type.

Comment: It may be of worth to note that the `IsMissing` function only works on the `Variant` type of optional parameter. More at [IsMissing function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445048(v=vs.60).aspx)